# Rspec expected 1 errors on :email, got 2

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a Factory in my code as :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Nitish'
    email 'nitishxyz@gmail.com'
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
  end
end
```

With a validation test written in rspec as :

```
it "is invalid without a unique email" do
user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: "nitishxyz@gmail.com", name: 'Buddha')
    expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:email)   
end
```

No other record with name 'Buddha' exists in the database.

The test fails with the error :

```
 Failure/Error: expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:email)
       expected 1 errors on :email, got 2
```

Why is it so? How do I check which is the other error on email?

Answer (score 0):

You can output `user.errors.inspect` to see what the other failure was.

Comment: I tried inspect but it was not showing any detailed information. So I chaned FactoryGirl.build to FactoryGirl.create. There is one error message repeating twice =>                                Failure/Error: user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "nitishupreti@gmail.com", name: 'Buddha')
     Mongoid::Errors::Validations:
       
       Problem:
         Validation of User failed.
       Summary:
         The following errors were found: Email is already taken, Email is already taken
       Resolution:
         Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations.